# Боковое меню.с Таббаром в одном приложении

Tags: swift

Всем доброго времени суток. Задача состоит в том, что надо сделать боковое меню с таббаром в одном приложении. Как можно переиспользовать тейблвью для всех контролеров таб бара. Чтоб по нажатию на элемент из списка меню, можно было еще и вернуться назад как в случае с навигейшнконтролером. Не могу найти абсолютно никакой информации ни на наших, ни на зарубежных порталах. Буду очень благодарен за любые советы и туториалы по теме) Ниже прикреплю макет сториборда как приблизительно должно выглядеть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не понимаю проблему, сделайте navigation контроллер перед вашим меню tableview, и при клике на ячейку делайте push на новый контроллер, у которого будет возможность вернуться в ваш tableview через pop.

Comment: Но мне надо возвращаться не на тейбл вью, а на один из контролеров таб бара, с которого я начинал переходить.